# Chrome autofill/ search suggestions gives away search information

Tags: google-chrome, browser, autocomplete, autofill

Chrome search/address field autocomplete/autofill/search suggestions should have an off switch. Does not having no off switch instantly give away information to possible snoopers?

Comment: Take a look here and see whether that resolves your "issue" : https://superuser.com/questions/562477/how-can-i-disable-chromes-address-bar-search-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Just use incognito mode when searching for anything suspicious lol.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Advanced > Sync and Google services > Auto-complete searches and URLs > Disable that option.